# Android native crash in libdvm.so

Tags: android, crash, xamarin, native

My app is crashing randomly, and I need some guidance on how to debug the native crash dump I see in logcat. This is a Xamarin/Android app that relies heavily on Bluetooth serial I/O.

Is there a genius out there that can read this dump and extract any useful information from it? What tools are available for me to make sense of this sort of output in the future?

```
 *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***  
 Build fingerprint: 'BLU/BLU/BLU:4.4.2/KOT49H/1420456435:user/release-keys'  
 pid: 29679, tid: 29679, name: tech.xxxxxxx  >>> [app name redacted] <<<
 signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
     r0 00000000  r1 000073ef  r2 00000006  r3 00000000
     r4 00000006  r5 0000000b  r6 000073ef  r7 0000010c
     r8 6ed51380  r9 62958dc0  sl 419759b8  fp bec9c160
     ip bec9c158  sp bec9be80  lr 4011d2b1  pc 4012c1f4  cpsr 000f0010    
 backtrace:
     #00  pc 000261f4  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
     #01  pc 000172ad  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+48)
     #02  pc 000174c1  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
     #03  pc 000161f5  /system/lib/libc.so
     #04  pc 00025aa4  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
     #05  pc 000472c7  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmAbort+78)
     #06  pc 00028a5c  /system/lib/libdvm.so (IndirectRefTable::get(void*) const+140)
     #07  pc 0004bbd1  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmDecodeIndirectRef(Thread*, _jobject*)+64)
     #08  pc 0004e825  /system/lib/libdvm.so
     #09  pc 0002ba9c  <unknown>    
 stack:
          bec9be40  bec9c158  [stack]
          bec9be44  6ed51380  
          bec9be48  62958dc0  
          bec9be4c  419759b8  
          bec9be50  bec9c160  [stack]
          bec9be54  40132470  /system/lib/libc.so (snprintf+124)
          bec9be58  62958d60  
          bec9be5c  419759a8  
          bec9be60  bec9bedc  [stack]
          bec9be64  00000000  
          bec9be68  00000000  
          bec9be6c  62958d28  
          bec9be70  00004000  
          bec9be74  bec9beea  [stack]
          bec9be78  e3a070ad  
          bec9be7c  ef9000ad  
     #00  bec9be80  00000006  
          bec9be84  0000000b  
          bec9be88  000073ef  
          bec9be8c  bec9c158  [stack]
          bec9be90  bec9c158  [stack]
          bec9be94  4011d2b1  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+52)
     #01  bec9be98  00000006  
          bec9be9c  00000354  
          bec9bea0  41972e58  
          bec9bea4  4011d4c5  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+14)
     #02  bec9bea8  bec9beb4  [stack]
          bec9beac  4011c1f9  /system/lib/libc.so    
 memory near r1:
     000073cc ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
     000073dc ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
     000073ec ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
     000073fc ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
     0000740c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
     0000741c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
     0000742c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
     0000743c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
     0000744c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
     0000745c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
     0000746c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
     0000747c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
     0000748c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
     0000749c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
     000074ac ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
     000074bc ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff      
 memory near r6:
     000073cc ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
     000073dc ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
     000073ec ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
     000073fc ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
     0000740c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
     0000741c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
     0000742c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
     0000743c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
     0000744c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
     0000745c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
     0000746c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
     0000747c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
     0000748c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
     0000749c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
     000074ac ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
     000074bc ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff      
 memory near r8:
     6ed51360 6ec12e70 00000000 6eea1680 00000000  
     6ed51370 0000004c 00000000 00000000 00000000  
     6ed51380 6b7698cc 6ec59fa8 735c9208 00000000  
     6ed51390 6ed51380 735c92a0 6ec97cb0 00000000  
     6ed513a0 6eea16d0 00000008 00000064 00000000  
     6ed513b0 00000000 00000000 6ed87fe0 00000000  
     6ed513c0 6eea1750 00000019 00000040 00020000  
     6ed513d0 00000000 6ed513e8 00000000 00000000  
     6ed513e0 00000000 0000010d 00000000 00000000  
     6ed513f0 6ec99b20 6faef620 6eea17a8 00000000  
     6ed51400 0000002c 00000000 00000000 00000000  
     6ed51410 6ed88168 00000000 6eea17d8 00000019  
     6ed51420 00000034 00020000 00000000 6ed51440  
     6ed51430 00000000 00000000 00000000 0000010d  
     6ed51440 00000000 00000000 6ed882b0 6f351940  
     6ed51450 6eea1818 00000008 00000074 00020000      
 memory near r9:
     62958da0 00000000 00000000 62958ddc 6b7f228c  
     62958db0 62d26a10 00000006 00000000 7a800019  
     62958dc0 ffffffff b100001d 62958dfc 654382c0  
     62958dd0 62d26ac0 6b7f228c 00000000 42abfaa8  
     62958de0 ffffffff 4314a128 62958e20 651eae28  
     62958df0 62d27050 654382c0 00000000 42abfaa8  
     62958e00 ffffffff 4314a128 4314a360 62958e3c  
     62958e10 651eae48 629f8880 651eae28 00000000  
     62958e20 4314a360 422d7af0 62958e5c 6542dfb8  
     62958e30 629f88c0 651eae48 00000000 4314a360  
     62958e40 42527178 422d7af0 62958eb0 651f2664  
     62958e50 629b8378 6542dfb8 00000000 00000000  
     62958e60 000073ef 0000278a 00000000 422d50d8  
     62958e70 00000001 422d7af0 62958eb0 651f2636  
     62958e80 000073ef 0000278a 422d50f8 42527178  
     62958e90 422d8d78 41c662f8 00000000 62958eec      
 memory near sl:
     41975998 0a426b00 00000800 62950008 0000045b  
     419759a8 6543143a 62958dbc 62d26ac0 6b8a7000  
     419759b8 422d7af0 00000000 bec9c508 00000000  
     419759c8 bec9c55c 00000001 00000000 419948c0  
     419759d8 00000000 00000000 61e1a670 62953300  
     419759e8 00000000 00000000 00000001 00006000  
     419759f8 00000000 400ee184 419948c0 41999740  
     41975a08 00000000 4199d83c 4199d8b0 4199d760  
     41975a18 4199d780 4199d7dc 00000000 00000000  
     41975a28 6f8ce2e0 00000028 6f8f0d51 bec9c508  
     41975a38 6543cec4 00000000 00000a4a 41a360ac  
     41975a48 00000000 629b1140 00000009 6ec4cce8  
     41975a58 00000001 00000100 00000200 00000000  
     41975a68 00000001 6543399a 6543399a 00000001  
     41975a78 655853bc 629b28e8 6dac4c16 5384f700  
     41975a88 63fa63d7 7f9a0c2a e0de70cd e7c42664      
 memory near fp:
     bec9c140 41a50950 bec9c160 00000001 00000000  
     bec9c150 6e0f0430 6eea3aa0 f2b00021 00000000  
     bec9c160 bec9c160 6dddc498 bec9c158 6e0f0418  
     bec9c170 6e0f0428 bec9c158 4314a400 4199e7fc  
     bec9c180 41972e58 1fe00ace 62a10800 6e0f0418  
     bec9c190 6de84398 6de83f28 00000000 bec9c160  
     bec9c1a0 6eea3990 bec9c160 0000001c 62d26a10  
     bec9c1b0 0000001c 62d26a10 f2b00021 00000000  
     bec9c1c0 0100003c 6dddb660 6de84398 6de83f28  
     bec9c1d0 6dddb658 bec9c1c8 6dddb658 bec9c2a0  
     bec9c1e0 6de84398 00000018 6dddb658 62d26a10  
     bec9c1f0 f2b00021 00000000 00000001 6dddc2c0  
     bec9c200 6ed50e3c 6de35d80 6de84398 6de83f28  
     bec9c210 6f6d12c0 bec9c200 6dddc2b4 bec9c310  
     bec9c220 6e0f03d0 bec9c2e0 6f6d12c0 62958dc0  
     bec9c230 419759b8 bec9c310 41972e58 1fe00ace      
 memory near ip:
     bec9c138 4314a400 41a30c64 41a50950 bec9c160  
     bec9c148 00000001 00000000 6e0f0430 6eea3aa0  
     bec9c158 f2b00021 00000000 bec9c160 6dddc498  
     bec9c168 bec9c158 6e0f0418 6e0f0428 bec9c158  
     bec9c178 4314a400 4199e7fc 41972e58 1fe00ace  
     bec9c188 62a10800 6e0f0418 6de84398 6de83f28  
     bec9c198 00000000 bec9c160 6eea3990 bec9c160  
     bec9c1a8 0000001c 62d26a10 0000001c 62d26a10  
     bec9c1b8 f2b00021 00000000 0100003c 6dddb660  
     bec9c1c8 6de84398 6de83f28 6dddb658 bec9c1c8  
     bec9c1d8 6dddb658 bec9c2a0 6de84398 00000018  
     bec9c1e8 6dddb658 62d26a10 f2b00021 00000000  
     bec9c1f8 00000001 6dddc2c0 6ed50e3c 6de35d80  
     bec9c208 6de84398 6de83f28 6f6d12c0 bec9c200  
     bec9c218 6dddc2b4 bec9c310 6e0f03d0 bec9c2e0  
     bec9c228 6f6d12c0 62958dc0 419759b8 bec9c310      
 memory near sp:
     bec9be60 bec9bedc 00000000 00000000 62958d28  
     bec9be70 00004000 bec9beea e3a070ad ef9000ad  
     bec9be80 00000006 0000000b 000073ef bec9c158  
     bec9be90 bec9c158 4011d2b1 00000006 00000354  
     bec9bea0 41972e58 4011d4c5 bec9beb4 4011c1f9  
     bec9beb0 00000000 ffffffdf 401682c4 4016822c  
     bec9bec0 00000000 4011edab 41a35940 41a35940  
     bec9bed0 00000354 4012baa8 00000000 419bd2cb  
     bec9bee0 422e7820 6c756e28 0000296c 00000000  
     bec9bef0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
     bec9bf00 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
     bec9bf10 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
     bec9bf20 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
     bec9bf30 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
     bec9bf40 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
     bec9bf50 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000      
 code around pc:
     4012c1d4 e8bd00f0 e3700a01 912fff1e e2600000  
     4012c1e4 ea00b702 e92d50f0 e3a07f43 ef000000  
     4012c1f4 e8bd50f0 e3700a01 912fff1e e2600000  
     4012c204 ea00b6fa e92d50f0 e3a070ee ef000000  
     4012c214 e8bd50f0 e3700a01 912fff1e e2600000  
     4012c224 ea00b6f2 00000000 00000000 e92d400f  
     4012c234 e1a03000 e1a00001 e1a01003 eb000040  
     4012c244 e8bd400f e12fff1e e320f000 e92d403f  
     4012c254 e2522040 ba00002c e1a05001 e2455c01  
     4012c264 f5d5f000 f5d5f040 f5d5f080 f5d5f0c0  
     4012c274 e2411040 e2400040 e1a05000 e1a04001  
     4012c284 f424020d f424420d f405022d f405422d  
     4012c294 e2522040 ba00001c e2411040 e2400040  
     4012c2a4 e1a05000 e1a04001 f424020d f424420d  
     4012c2b4 f405022d f405422d e2522040 ba000012  
     4012c2c4 e2411040 e2400040 e1a05000 e1a04001      
code around lr:
     4011d290 447b4b13 42b3e010 4812d10e 44786a1e  
     4011d2a0 eb08f7f8 e9d8f00d 46224631 ef9cf00e  
     4011d2b0 d00a3001 e00b2400 2b00681b 480ad1eb  
     4011d2c0 44782403 eaf6f7f8 f001e002 6804fa1b  
     4011d2d0 fa18f001 46206005 bf00bd70 0005095a  
     4011d2e0 0005094e 00050946 00050922 bf7ef7ff  
     4011d2f0 43f0e92d 4a3d4b3c 589c447b 6823b08b  
     4011d300 460d4606 f0019309 46a1f9fd 8000f8d0  
     4011d310 d0482d00 f00f4628 280ffed5 d8444604  
     4011d320 ffe4f7ff d1064286 4629200f e8a2f00d  
     4011d330 d03c2800 482ee02e f7f84478 482dea3a  
     4011d340 e0154478 d11342b0 482b6a06 f7f84478  
     4011d350 4a2aeab2 447a2120 a8014633 e84af015  
     4011d360 a8012101 ef52f021 46061c42 e011d104  
     4011d370 28006800 e02cd1e6 46294630 f00d4622  
     4011d380 1c43e8de d11e4607 f9bcf001 29046801
```

Comment: Nobody can debug dumps. Some code of yours would be helpful.

Comment: Problem is I have no idea what code in the app was running at the time this occurred. There's no traceability across the app/native border.

Comment: All right, than here's some guidance. Try to get android log after crash 'adb logcat > log.txt'. Also here's some instructions how to capture HCI log https://www.nowsecure.com/blog/2014/02/07/bluetooth-packet-capture-android/. Maybe something will show up.